# Is there any way to run a custom maven clean just for a specific profile?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, build-process, pom.xml

So, I have a maven profile which generates my StaticMetaModel (ClassName_.java) classes for my JPA entities (ClassName.java).

Then, i defined my maven-clean-plugin to delete those generated classes every time I run mvn clean.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*_.java</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        <filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is the profile that generates the MetaModel.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                <processors>
                     <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Everything works as intended, but I would like for maven clean to perform with normal configuration (without deleting those generated classes) when I want to run other profiles. **Is there any way to have two methods for cleaning the project and running the custom one just for the generation profile?**

Comment: have you tried maven profiles ? so you can do "mvn clean -Pprofile1"

Comment: @Neil Stockton Yes, I have a profile for generating those classes. When i run mvn clean install -PgenerateMetaProfile the ClassName_.java files are deleted and recreated. But when I run mvn clean install -PotherProfile I don't want to delete those classes.

Comment: Generating into `src/main/` is in general the wrong way...generating code should be done into `target` folder...Than you don't need such weird constructions...

Comment: @khmarbaise I know, but I have some other classes that depend on those StaticMetaModels and I don't want to manually modify and create a model each time I add/modify one of my Entities.

Comment: @AndreiPopescu You should generate during the usual life cycle and don't do that manually...I don't see the point? Can you show your full pom file?

Comment: Your problem is that you're generating sources under `src/main/java`. **Don't do that. Ever. Period.** If you didn't do it, you wouldn't have that problem right now. Cleaning under `src/main/java` makes no sense and against every good practice there is.

Comment: @khmarbaise I edited the original post and added the profile configuration. I managed to solve it actually just now, by defining that custom clean configuration, inside the profile. And now, in any other profiles, it cleans normally.

Comment: Your real problem is right there --> `<outputDirectory>src/main/java/</outputDirectory>`. I strongly suggest you to not do that.

Comment: @Tunaki, I understand that, but that profile is used just for development purposes. It will be deleted entirely once it hits production.The whole purpose for using this method, is because there are over 150 entities and I would like to not create/modify the StaticMetaModel everytime I change something. The MetaModels are being used inside other classes that use the CriteriaAPI, so I need them to exists over there.

Comment: @AndreiPopescu Still, this is not a reason to do it. You generated sources under `target` and you add them to your build-path with [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-souce`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) (if it's not already done by the plugin generating those sources)

Comment: @Tunaki, thank you, I will try using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, using @Tunaki 's sugestion. So thank you. Here's my solution.

In the plugins section, I left the maven-clean-plugin unaltered.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
```

then, in the profiles section, I defined my generation profile to generate sources, in a new src-gen/main/java folder. I needed to delete first the generated sources, so I configured the clean plugin just for this profile to delete the src-gen folder.

```
<profile>
        <id>hibernate-processor</id>
        <properties>
            <environment.id>hibernate-processor</environment.id>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src-gen</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>src-gen/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                <processors>
                                    <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                                </processors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

After that, I added the src-gen/main/java as a sources folder using build-helper-maven-plugin as @Tunaki said.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src-gen/main/java/</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Lastly, I just had to configure the maven-compiler-plugin to also compile the .java files in the src-gen/main/java folder.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
                <include>src-gen/main/java/**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```